# I'm trying to filter on a table calculation. The grand total doesn't change when trying to filter on a Table calc. Its static

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to filter on a measure that is a table calculation and the grand total doesn't change.  It only changes when the filter is on a dimension.

I tried to duplicate the data source but that didn't work.

When filtering on table calc, provide a new grand total.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the Tableau Calculation filter won't run before the aggregations have been made. That's why you aren't seeing a different Grand Total when filtering by the table calculation.

This is explained in Tableau's [Order of Operations](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/order_of_operations.htm)

[image]

If you want to see a different Grand Total your filter will need to come before the Measures you are aggregating in the Order of Operation.

You can think of Tableau Calculations as visual filters, meaning they can change what is rendering on the screen, but won't affect the underlying data.